# In next js how do I parse cookie which value is an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cookies

I'm trying to parse a cookie which was an object.
Here is my code.

inputform.js

```
async function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let cookieBody = {};
    if (ifSmoke === "흡연") {
      cookieBody = {
        age: age,
        gender: gender,
        height: height,
        weight: weight,
        ifSmoke: ifSmoke,
        howMuchSmoke: howMuchSmoke,
        howManySmoke: howManySmoke,
        diseases: diseases,
      };
    } else {
      cookieBody = {
        age: age,
        gender: gender,
        height: height,
        weight: weight,
        ifSmoke: ifSmoke,
        diseases: diseases,
      };
    }
const respond = await fetch("/api/cookie", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(cookieBody),
    }).then((res) => res.json());
    console.log(respond);
    console.log(cookieBody);

    if (respond.result === "success") {
      router.push("/analyzing");
    }
```

route.js

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

export async function POST(request) {
  const body = await request.json();

  cookies().set("formData", body);

  return Response.json({ result: "success" });
}
```

analyzing.js

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const Analyzing = () => {
  let a = cookies().get("formData").value;
  console.log(typeof a);
  return <div>Enter</div>;
};

export default Analyzing;
```

I make a cookie that has an object value at inputform.js and send it to the api handler to make a cookie. After that route to another page and get the cookie I made.
But the result was just an encoded string and JSON.parse didn't worked.
Is there a way to parse this object value cookie?

Comment: You need to stringify before storing the data.